# Spotify App - Facebook Auth logout procedure

Tags: facebook, oauth, spotify

In the Spotify App's API docs there is a module to [authenticate via Facebook](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/09321954e7.html) - now I try to find a way to logout from Facebook but can't find any documentation about the correct procedure. The Facebook Javascript SDK provides a logout method via `FB.logout()` for this - how about the Spotify API?!

Answer (score 3):

In order to log out, you need to make a GET request to the Facebook's logout URL, which at the moment is https://www.facebook.com/logout.php, passing two parameters:

- `access_token`: It is the access token provided by Facebook when access to the user's account was requested.
- `next`: It is a URL that has to be part of the domain URL that was set on Facebook's app profile.

Logging out is performed by making an AJAX call to that URL. If it was successful, a redirection to the `next` URL will me made. Otherwise, the redirection will be made to http://www.facebook.com/home.php (for instance, if the `next` URL doesn't belong to the registered app domain).

You can read the response of that AJAX call and check that the content you get is that from your `next` URL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Facebook API - if you look at the documentation, you'll see that `auth.authenticateWithFacebook` is just a thin wrapper around `auth.showAuthenticationDialog`. It doesn't actually interact with Facebook's "proper" API at all - it only loads Facebook's login page and gives you a callback when the user is logged in.